# How to sort a Java list of objects using a RuleBasedCollator on a field?

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort an `ArrayList` of objects on a specific field using a given [`RuleBasedCollator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).

For example, we have a list of `Thing` objects:

```
public Thing {
  public String name;
  public String type;
}

List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();

RuleBasedCollator ruleBasedCollator = new RuleBasedCollator("< Table < Plate < Fork < Knife");
```

Now, after having created `Thing` objects and added them to the `things` list, I want to sort this list, getting first things of `type` "table" and last things of type "knife".

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: @Raedwald From `java.text`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution using a TreeMap. I use the "type" property for the key and a list of Thing for the value. Instead of using a RuleBasedCollator, I created a ListBasedCollator extending Collator, because RuleBasedCollator rules work on characters but not on words.

```
public class ListBasedCollator extends Collator {

private List<String> list;

public ListBasedCollator(String[] array) {
    list = Arrays.asList(array);
}

@Override
public int compare(String source, String target) {
    if(!list.contains(target)) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(!list.contains(source)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return Integer.valueOf(list.indexOf(source)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(list.indexOf(target)));
}

@Override
public CollationKey getCollationKey(String source) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Here is how I construct the TreeMap:

```
String[] sortingList = {"TABLE", "PLATE", "FORK", "KNIFE"};
ListBasedCollator listBasedCollator = new ListBasedCollator(sortingList);
Map<String, List<Thing>> thingMap = new TreeMap<String, List<Thing>>(listBasedCollator);
```

So, the thingMap will always be sorted by type using the listBasedCollator.
And I can also sort alphabetically the list of things for each different type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, instead of using compareTo in compare method of Comparator you can call RuleBasedCollator's compare.

```
mQueue.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    if (o1.getDescription().getTitle() != null && o2.getDescription().getTitle() != null) {
        return mRuleBasedCollator.compare(o1.getDescription().getTitle().toString(),
            o2.getDescription().getTitle().toString());
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand a `RuleBaseCollator` is intended for sorting `String`s, at least i says so in  the Collator class which is the super class. I would instead use a Comparator, something like this:

```
public class ThingSorter {
public enum ThingType{      
    //wanted sort order, sort on ordinal :
    //Table < Plate < Fork < Knife      
    TABLE, PLATE, FORK, KNIFE
}

public static class Thing {
    private String name;
    private ThingType type;

    public Thing(String name, ThingType tt) {
        this.name = name;
        type = tt;          
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " [" + type + "]";
    }
}

public static class MyThingComparator implements Comparator<Thing> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Thing t1, Thing t2) {
        return t1.type.ordinal() - t2.type.ordinal();
    }
}
public static class MyReverseThingComparator implements Comparator<Thing> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Thing t1, Thing t2) {
        return t2.type.ordinal() - t1.type.ordinal();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();
    things.add(new Thing("One", ThingType.KNIFE));
    things.add(new Thing("Two", ThingType.FORK));
    things.add(new Thing("Three", ThingType.PLATE));
    things.add(new Thing("Four", ThingType.TABLE));
    System.out.println("unsorted:\n" + things);

    Collections.sort(things, new MyThingComparable());  
    System.out.println("sorted:\n" + things);

    Collections.sort(things, new MyReverseThingComparable());   
    System.out.println("sorted:\n" + things);
}
```

}

The names are are not involved in the sorting in this case just the type (and the ordinal in the type)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution that seems to be working well. However, you turn my "type" property into an predefined enum, and in my case, it's important to keep it in String. I finally found another solution with TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly use the `TreeMap` or `enum` as the previous answers suggest; a rather simpler alternative is to use *just* a custom compatator, without the `enum`. If you're using Java 8 you can get it down to a single line:

```
Collections.sort(things,
                 (Thing t1, Thing t2)->ruleBasedCollator.compare(t1.type, t2.type) );
```

The pre-8 version would do the same thing with an anonymous `Comparator`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know this new Java8 syntax that sounds pretty good.